# flask pagination query sample?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, flask

i am following a flask pagination tutorial here: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/44/

I just have confusion in this code:

```
from flask import redirect

PER_PAGE = 20

@app.route('/users/', defaults={'page': 1})
@app.route('/users/page/<int:page>')
def show_users(page):
    count = count_all_users()
    users = get_users_for_page(page, PER_PAGE, count)
    if not users and page != 1:
        abort(404)
    pagination = Pagination(page, PER_PAGE, count)
    return render_template('users.html',
        pagination=pagination,
        users=users
    )
```

as you can see below count is a function count_all_users(), should i query for the count of all the rows of users table?
and below count is the variable users, i just dont get this code:

```
users = get_users_for_page(page, PER_PAGE, count)
```

how do i perform a query for this? is there any sample with this around? i just have difficulty finding one. I am using postgresql, i would really appreciate if you could help me structure a logical query for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that returns 4 items per page, with the current page number as 1. The Pagination class used on the snippet is custom, [FLask-SQLAlchemy's Pagination](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.paginate) is much better.

```
@app.route('/result', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def result():
    results = Foo.query.paginate(per_page=4, error_out=True, page=1)
    return render_template('results.html', results=results)
```